# How can I locally manage C manuals?

Tags: c

My Googling results in a huge amount of unnecessary results with C. My hope is to get the best C manuals local. I find the reference useful  [here.](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/) I would like to make my own notes and removal to the manual.

> Can I manage it somehow like a local manual?

**Feedback to the repliers worried about the law**

Please, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009815/iframes-and-law/1072208#1072208) about some law philosophies:

1. lex mercatoria
2. lex retis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like wget to grab the site and store it locally.

You could then edit the pages yourself, adding/removing content you see fit.

This worked for me:

```
  wget --mirror -w 2 -p --convert-links http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/
```

Comment: Did he say he was going to be redistributing it? I did not read that anywhere in his post. I believe it's fair use to make local changes to content that no one else will ever see.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure the author would like you copying their work.  So my answer does not apply to your question about managing the manual locally.  One thing you can do is to use [web annotation tools](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/web-annotation-tools-research-annotate-collaborate/) to manage your own notes.  Take note of that little pesky notice at the top "**© Copyright 1997 Eric Huss**" and please respect it.

Comment: Upvoting since I think this is the only answer that doesn't advocate copyright violation and there's too many others to downvote :-)

Comment: Are there any exceptions to copyright law for "fair use?"  I'm not a lawyer, so I don't really know

Comment: § 107. Limitations on exclusive rights: Fair use40

....
(including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research, is not an infringement of copyright. In determining whether the use made of a work in any particular case is a fair use the factors to be considered shall include —

Comment: http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#107  This seems a little fuzzy to me.  It looks like you can have fair use for research purposes, but it seems to indicate that there might be restrictions on the amount of the work that you copy.  Who knows

Comment: The major reasons these apply is that the work is original and the author has claimed ownership by claiming copyright.  Digital reproduction falls directly into these statutes.

Comment: ojblass, how do you interpret this?  I'm honestly just curious, I'm not really up on copyright law (not trying to argue with you).

Comment: My personal interpretation is that this law is not black and white, it sounds like it's case-by-case, and would have to be decided in court.

Comment: I think to fall under one of the exceptions he would have to be a recognized non-profit organization.  (1) the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;

Comment: Imagine if you could simply copy everything from MSNBC and then put it on your own website sans advertisements.

Comment: What if you just copied it down to your local machine though.  I think this is slightly different, I doubt this guy is going to republish any of this, it sounds like he just wants a disconnected copy.

Comment: Anyway, I think you make a valid point, it's probably safer to not make a copy, and just go buy a book or something.

Comment: I think printing or downloading a single page could be considered fair use for educational purposes.  Once you drill down and take the whole things with tools you cross a line.  I am all about information sharing but I have purchased fuits of my labor on the black market in Bangkok and it has made me overly sensitive to such things.

Comment: It would be a case-by-case trial if you ended in a court. There are two dominating law philosophies for the web "lex mercatoria" and "lex retis". More by a lawyer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009815/iframes-and-law/1072208#1072208.

Answer (score 3):

Most answers bring up the legality of the thing or lack thereof.

Actually, I am not so sure making a local copy of a website strictly for personal use constitutes copyright infringement.

First of all, there is no mention of where the person is located, so we don't even know what copyright laws apply. For instance, Canada and Australia have some explicit positions regarding personal use of lawfully acquired properties, and I believe there are a few rulings in the US along the same line.

Second, by visiting a website, you are automatically making a personal copy using a software called a browser. This is not, I believe, a copyright violation.

Should the user use an offline browser of some kind (like wget) to visit the website and store it on his hard drive, I do not see why this would be prohibited in anyway.

Antecedents and context are also important. If you consider that most websites are archived and made publicly available by the wayback machine (see http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide), an usage which is not challenged (archive.org is based in the US), it is pretty difficult to make a valid argument against a private copy intented as a personal reference.

In short, I don't think making a personal copy of a website for strictly private use is a violation of current copyright laws in most countries.

On the other end, distributing the said copy would be a different matter entirely.

Comment: Legally, it is a huge gray area. Ethically is another matter. It is simply wrong. A separate question is why an entire book is apparently available for download at an unrestricted URL in conflict with its internal copyright notice. Probably only the author can shed light on that.

Comment: Why wrong? What is wrong about it?

My assumption is that if a book is posted in an open format on a website without any kind of protection, whoever posted it did so with the intention to share the content. 

I have about a book's worth of articles on my website. I am perfectly fine with anyone downloading it for personal use. After all, I wrote it to make that info available. Still it's copyrighted and people can't publish it without my OK.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/ and you will see a c guide tar file.  I suspect you could download that file, expand it on your local system, and then annotate at will.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to do this download the entire manual using your browser, wget or whichever tool you have available. Next create a bookmark to the files on your hard drive or optionally install a local webserver to link to. Finally, you can add notes by editing the files, or by using annotations as ojblass suggests.

Also, here's another I find handy, an archive of some [comp.lang.c](http://c-faq.com/index.html) posts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you could buy [Harbison and Steele](http://www.careferencemanual.com/).

The one you link is marked copyright 1997, so I'd suggest you write the author at e-huss@uiuc.edu and ask permission.  But there's nothing preventing you from using [wget](http://linuxreviews.org/man/wget/) to download a copy.

Comment: Why Harbison and Steele when there's K&R's C Programming Language (http://tr.im/KRCPL2ED)?

Comment: You mean nothing other than the fact it's illegal?

Comment: @Pax: are you sure this is illegal? There is no mention of which country's law apply, and we are talking about personal use, which is authorized in quite a few places.

Comment: @oj, @OJ, there's nothing a lot more pointless than debating legalities with non-lawyers, and any debate I'm in would include at least one non-lawyer.  But consider, if he *reads* the whole book he's fetched every page of it. wget-ing it for local reading doesn't damage the author.  Nor does writing marginal notes on it.  Republishing the result certainly would.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the web page ("Save Webpage Complete") to your local drive.

There are also a lot of PDF versions of C manuals.  Search google for "c manual pdf" - the first result is one by Dennis Ritchie.

(Beware copyright violations though, I'm not really clear on when you can make personal copies under "fair use".)

If you're on Unix, a lot of the C library is available as man pages.  E.g. "man memcpy", "man malloc", etc.

Comment: That first paragraph is clear incitement to copyright violation. The second may be, depending on the status of those PDFs. The third paragraph is good but I find I can get similar results by typing "man malloc" (with quotes) into Google. But DON'T do this with "man man", that's not a work-suitable way to get the manpage for man itself.

Comment: That might be true, I don't know.  It seems like copying down a reference manual or PDF for personal research/education might fall under fair use (I don't know).  Can you point out any specific part of copyright law that restricts this?

Answer (score 0):

Most C functions are already described on your system in the manpages.  For instance, `man floor` will give you the documentation for the floor function.  Sometimes there is a conflict between a function and commandline program.  A good example of this is `man printf` which gives you the manpage for the `printf` command (`printf(1)`).  At the end of the page you will normally find a `SEE ALSO` section that lists other places to look.  In this case you should see `printf(3)`.  You can display that page by saying `man 3 printf`.